# Image Loader during AJAX/JSON Process

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, image, loader

I have been trying to get an Image loader to show up that will cover the entire document during ajaxStart and hiding on ajaxStop as follows:

Script:

```
$(this).ajaxStart(function(){
         $().addClass('imageLoader');
    });

    $(this).ajaxStop(function(){
           $().removeClass('imageLoader');
    });
```

CSS:

```
.imageLoader { 
background: #f5f3e5 url('images/common/loading.gif') 50% no-repeat; top }
```

It doesn't show the image as intended, although I know the ajaxStart/Stop are working when I tested it with some other sample code (i.e. Changing some text color to red).

Is there a better way of implementing this? 
I can't seem to understand what the issue is.

Comment: Is it the path to your image file? Try /images/common/loading.gif because what you have wont work unless the images directory is in the same location as your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you set up an hidden div with the class and show/hide it

```
<div style="display:none" class="imageLoader" id="loader"></div>

$(this).ajaxStart(function(){
         $('#loader).show();
    });

    $(this).ajaxStop(function(){
         $('#loader).hide();
    });
```

Comment: IN addition, how can I make it so that the user can't click on anything in the background. In other words, they can only see the image loader and that's it, or would this also solve this issue

Comment: same just design your div to cover all the visible are and it won t allow users to click any other thing.